# How to enforce CloudTableClient to use default proxy which is configured in IE or use a proxy address to connect to the internet

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

I am getting the following exception when i try to connect from my code. But NeudesicLLC's  AzureStorageExplorer is able to connect by detecting the proxy server settings which is configured in IE. Is there anyway to enforce the CloudTableClient to use the proxy settings?

The remote name could not be resolved: 'mystorage.table.core.windows.net', stack trace    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryAsyncResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudTableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(String tableName)

Comment: I do this all the time from Microsoft, and my proxy settings seem to be picked up fine... anything unusual about your proxy or your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks smarx. your comment confirmed me that proxy settings are picked by default. so i went and changed the log-on user for my windows service who is internet user, it worked. Thanks a lot. Earlier the service was configured to run as local system account. So its nothing to do with AzureClient. The fault was on the windows service user configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can set the proxy settings with the system.net/defaultproxy of the configuration file like the following

```
<configuration>
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        proxyaddress="http://MyProxyServer"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```